# Thoughts on security in linux

Tags: permissions, dual-boot, virtual-machine, malware

So ransomware is around again - at least in Denmark. This is a major issue for MS-Windows users, but does almost never affect Linux or Mac. The reason is an issue of debate. But since the consumer market is changing we may see more malware specifically written for other platforms in the future. Anyway I did a bit of research on how malware infects PCs and spreads, and I did have a look on my own system. It seems that if an unknowing user by accident runs a script containing malware that script runs with the same permissions as the user that started it and usually searches for a specific subdirectory to store its own files; not an immediate problem if the (windows) folder doesn't exist on the system. However what if a user has named a subdirectory by the name that the malware searches and has given write permissions for that directory? Might the malware be able to run on a system for which it was not intended?

Anyway I'm using Windows in a virtual machine for the very few programs I still have that only run on Windows. According to some employees in security companies interviewed by press for this latest threat virtual machines could be a problem - and it's the same case with dual boot. The Windows directories does not seem to exist on my system except inside a virtual disk image file. My guess is that if Windows malware enter my system from Linux it can't find the appropriate subdirectory for its files. However if the malware script is run inside my virtual machine it should probably be able to install, run and read/write to all shared folders according to the virtual machines permissions settings and by that spread to the whole of my data partition. Is that correctly understood and would the issue not be the same if the system is set up for dual boot with read and write permissions to a common data partition?

Now back to Linux. Assume for a moment that a malware script is written for Linux, placed on a hacked website to be downloaded when the website is visited. Suppose a user has a few scripts that should be run e.g. on startup, and the user has write and execute permissions to a directory from which files are executed on startup. Would appropriately written malware be able to install itself in any such directory and thus compromise the system or even "just" the users account?

Comment: "all users have read write and execute permissions in those directories"? WHAT?! Did you run `chmod` on them? What does `find /etc -perm /o=w ! -type l` say?

Comment: @muru they may be misunderstanding symlink permissions...

Comment: @JeffSchaller could be, but how many symlinked *directories* are present in `/etc`? I couldn't spot any on my Arch or Ubuntu systems.

Comment: Maybe the OP can elaborate?

Comment: Losing is spelled l-o-s-i-n-g.

Comment: @muru the command returns 3 lines similar to `find \`/etc/cups/ssl': Permission denied`. @JeffSchaller the files I saw are in subdiredtories `rc*.d` and are indeed symbolic links to files in `init.d` to which only root has write permissions (except for two other symbolic links) .

Answer (score 1):

> I noticed on my system that though root is the owner of the
>   directories in /etc/* where files that are run on startup, reboot and
>   shutdown etc. are placed, all users have read write and execute
>   permissions in those directories.

No Linux distro would set up /etc like that.  Certainly there are parts of /etc that the user must be able to read from (such as /etc/bashrc) but never to write to.

You could certainly exploit a web browser to get it to write to the unprivledged user's home directory, into /tmp and a couple other directories, but without turning off many security features and running the web browser as root, there's no easy way for the web browser to write anything into /etc.